# How to check when the website is loading on the another specific site (using iframe)

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

Web site **A** is loading on a web site **B** and on a few other websites using iframe.

How can I check when site **A** is loading just on website **B**.

It is important to see when it is loading on site **B** so I can include my CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If site A is also under your control then while loading site B, you can pass extra param while calling site B from A like theme=a.

Try

```
parent.location.href;
```

or

```
parent.location.url;
```

Comment: I can't add $_GET variable because unfortunately client doesn't want that.

Comment: You can try parent.location.href; also

Comment: If the sites are on different domains, you cannot access parent.anything

Comment: @mplungjan - sites are on different domains.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`. It doesn't tell you whether your site was loaded through `<iframe>` or user just clicked a link, but at least it will tell you the address where user came from.

Comment: Yes, but when user click on some link inside of iframe then referer changes. I can't store in COOKIE because then will load my css when user realy visit Web site A and I can't add $_GET variable because client doesn't want that.

Comment: Why would client care what does the link inside look like? There isn't even an address field in iframe.

Comment: I don't have source code of Web site A. I must find solution and send to client. Client is inserting my solution (code). :(